# Unable to use addObject method on a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

So I have a NSMutanbleArray (which is called users) and actually I'm not able to use the addObject method on it.

Here is my code:

```
 #import "GroupRestBeans.h"
    #import "User.h"

    @interface GroupRestBeans()

    @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *name;
    @property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray<User *> *users;

    @end

    @implementation GroupRestBeans

    -(instancetype)init{
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            _users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void)newUser:(User *)user{
        [self.users addObject:user]; //Here there is an error:
                                     //No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'addObject:'
    }

    - (NSArray *)users {
        return _users;
    }

    @end
```

I don't know why, and I'm doing exactly the same in an other class...
If someone could help I would appreciate, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have `users` declared as a public property, but typed as `NSArray`?

Comment: You are initialize `_users` and try to `addObject` in `self.users`. Obvious is the same, but probably for the xcode in this case may not be. try `[_users addObject:user];`

Comment: Yes that's what I found, you're right!